# nlog not creating file

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-5, nlog

As per tutorials, when some exception is thrown, it will write exceptions in a text file. But in my case, when some exception is thrown, I am not able to detect that file of exception in any of the folder.

I had install Nlog.config from nuget and used

```
var  _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

//In Controller
 _logger.Error(ex, "StringErrorMessage");
```

and this is my Nlog.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">
  <variable name="myvar" value="myvalue"/>
  <variable name="logDirectory" value="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}"/>
  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/file.txt" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <!-- add your logging rules here -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: do you have any Nlog error in c:\temp\nlog-internal.log?

Comment: I had time to create a test project. Using the same exact config as you shared, I could log an error into the file. Make sure to look in the /bin/debug/logs/{date}/file.txt

Comment: is there nothing logged or not the exception? Also check the internal log with `internalLogLevel=debug`.

Comment: Also enable `throwExceptions` for debugging

Answer (score 0):

Old question but someone still might look at it.

Does the file `c:\temp\nlog-internal.log` exist ?

If not, set `Copy to Output Directory` property of your nlog.config file to `Copy always`.